# Is checking that a property doesn't throw an exception a valid unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exceptions, properties

I'm writing tests for the following class:

```
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private int _failCount;
  private int _totalCount;
  public double FailRate
  {
     get
     {
        double returnValue = 0.0;
        if (_totalCount > 0)
        {
           returnValue = (double) _failCount / _totalCount * 100;
        }
        return returnValue;
     }
  }

  public int FailCount
  {
     get { return _failCount; }
     set
     {
        if (value != _failCount)
        {
           _failCount = value;
           onNotifyPropertyChanged();
           onNotifyPropertyChanged("FailRate");
        }
     }
  }
  public int TotalCount
  {
     get { return _totalCount; }
     set
     {
        if (value != _totalCount)
        {
           _totalCount = value;
           onNotifyPropertyChanged();
           onNotifyPropertyChanged("FailRate");
        }
     }
  }
  protected virtual void onNotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = null)
  {
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
     {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
     }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I was writing some tests for the `FailRate` property, and it occurred to me that I should probably make sure that getting `FailRate` doesn't throw an exception.  The case being someone (probably me) removes the `if (_totalCount > 0)` check, and then getting `FailRate` throws a `DivideBy0Exception`.

So I wrote a test that makes sure getting `FailRate` doesn't throw an exception.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GettingTheFailRateWhenTheTotalCountIsZeroDoesNotThrowAnException()
{
   Defect defect = new Defect();
   defect.FailCount = 0;
   defect.TotalCount = 0;
   double dummy = defect.FailRate;
}
```

However, that test doesn't have an explicit check, and will pass as long as the property doesn't throw an exception.

Is just checking that a property doesn't throw an exception a "valid" test?

Comment: It's really up to you to determine whether or not a test is worth doing. If you feel safer doing that test, that's already a good enough reason to run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, yes. All logic - meaning all conditional code - can be tested. And this is an edge case, too.

By the way, this code is not thread-safe - `_totalCount` could change between reading its value in if and actually dividing by it. But thread-safety might not be among your requirements.

As for the check being explicit or not, it's a matter of taste. You could catch `DivideByZeroException` and call `Assert.Fail` (or whatever it's called) in the `catch` block. More verbose, but very clear for the reader. As a fellow coder, I'd be okay either way.

And that the routine being tested is so simple? Mixing imperial and metric units crashed a space probe worth $125 million, and this doesn't sound like a very sophisticated bug.

Maybe someone is going to write a similar piece of code for this project - calculating estimated time left, for instance - and having seen this test will prevent a mental lapse by reminding them there are zeroes in this world and zero can't be divided by? It can't hurt...

Answer (score 7):

> Is just checking that a property doesn't throw an exception a "valid" test?

Yes, it can be. In this example, I would explicitly check that `FailRate` returns 0 for that input.

And I certainly would validate that the bad input is handled properly by writing the test. I'd probably write a test with a negative value as well to make sure it was `> 0` rather than `== 0` since it takes like 10 seconds and better encodes the requirements into the test.